# Problema estamento if de una funcion en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

> Buenas, tengo un problemilla y es que solo me funciona la primera vez que le doy, es decir , el primer `if` (lo que me lo oculta), pero al volver a darle no me lo muestra y se queda ocultado los elementos

```
function funcion_ocultar_mostrar () {
    var visible = true;

    //ocultar
    if(visible === true){
        textarea.style.display = 'none';
        btn_enviar.style.display = 'none';
        btn_ocultar.innerHTML= 'Mostrar';



        console.log('ocultar');

    }

    //mostrar
    else if(visible === false){
        //textarea.style.display = 'none';
        textarea.style.display = 'block';
        btn_enviar.style.display = 'block';
        btn_ocultar.innerHTML= 'Ocultar';



        console.log('mostrar');
    }

    visible = !visible;
}
```

> tambien puede ser que que no lo este haciendo bien a la hora de volverlo a mostrar. No lo se , no estoy muy seguro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
function funcion_ocultar_mostrar () {

    //ocultar
    if(textarea.style.display !== "none"){
        textarea.style.display = 'none';
        btn_enviar.style.display = 'none';
        btn_ocultar.innerHTML= 'Mostrar';



        console.log('ocultar');

    }

    //mostrar
    else if(textarea.style.display !== "block"){
        textarea.style.display = 'block';
        btn_enviar.style.display = 'block';
        btn_ocultar.innerHTML= 'Ocultar';



        console.log('mostrar');
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto!! Muchas gracias. Una ultima duda, cuando debo usar en los if esto '==' o esto '===' ?

Comment: Aquí te explica como usar los operadores lógicos de javascript https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=795:operadores-logicos-javascript-relacionales-igual-distinto-and-or-not-prioridades-ejemplos-cu01117e&catid=78&Itemid=206

Comment: en JavaScrip como buena practica se recomienda usar `===` para comparación, ya que muchos tipos de datos dicen ser `true` con `==`.